# mySQL Join Transaction Owner from Owner History

Tags: mysql, join

I have a transaction table, and need to join to each transaction to who the owner was at that time:

*Transaction (t)*

```
+----+---------------------+---------+--------+
| id |        date         | details | itemID |
+----+---------------------+---------+--------+
|  1 | 2017-03-02 22:35:01 | info    |    123 |
|  2 | 2017-02-02 22:35:01 | info    |    123 |
|  3 | 2016-01-01 22:35:01 | info    |    123 |
+----+---------------------+---------+--------+
```

*TransferHistory (th)*

```
+----+---------------------+--------+------------+------------+
| id |        date         | itemID | newOwnerID | oldOwnerID |
+----+---------------------+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2017-02-25 22:35:01 |    123 |        222 |        333 |
|  2 | 2017-02-02 20:35:01 |    123 |        333 |        444 |
|  3 | 2015-01-01 22:35:01 |    123 |        444 |        555 |
+----+---------------------+--------+------------+------------+
```

*Item*

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| id |   details   | ownerID |
+----+-------------+---------+
|123 | thing1      |     123 |
|  1 | other thing |     127 |
|  2 | big thing   |     129 |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

I am able to join the current owner through the *item* table, but how would I join the owner at each transaction date based on the *TransferHistory* table?

The result I am looking for is:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| t.id |       t.date        | t.details | t.itemID | th.ownerID |
+------+---------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
|    1 | 2017-03-02 22:35:01 | sale      |      123 |        222 |
|    2 | 2017-02-02 22:35:01 | something |      123 |        333 |
|    3 | 2016-01-01 22:35:01 | traded    |      123 |        444 |
+------+---------------------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: looking to you expected  resusl seems that you need  the th.newOwnerId for same itemID and date  .  is correct ?  but what's for t.details .. from where yo get the values sale, somethings, traded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way (in MySQL) is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select th.newOwnerId
        from transferhistory th
        where th.date <= t.date
        order by th.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as OwnerId_atdate
from transactions t;
```

Note:  This assumes that the transfer history has a record for the first owner.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I was a bit worried about this approach due to performance, but it seems to be the best approach with what I have to work with.